# Thread deadlock relevant to methods GetConnection() from DriverManager and next() from Scanner, System.in

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, stdin

I need your help regarding following problem:
I have **two threads**.

**First** thread: is supposed to read user for input using Scanner class from standard input

> Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

and is waitng for whole string. This thread **got first** to the method next().

**Second** thread arrives after and is trying to open a connection using jdbc - odbc.

> connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:baza");

What is happening is that method getConnection() and second thread are blocked by first one. My question is why is this happening? How can i prevent that?

I've created small code from my project so it's easier to read..

One more thing i am interested is why

> Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

is optional. My program works with and without it? Does java load driver by default?

Code:

```
public class StartingHere implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SECOND THREAD
        try {
            StartingHere sh =  new StartingHere();
            Thread thread = new Thread(sh);
            thread.start();
            //DELAYING SECOND THREAD. 
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Check db url for in DBConnection");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //FIRST THREAD - Waiting for user to input String
        String userInput = null;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!"end".equals(userInput)) {
            //Waiting for whole string
            userInput = scanner.next();
        }
    }
}

public class DBConnection {
    Connection connection;

    public DBConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        // SECOND THREAD- Problem! Here program hangs until FIRST THREAD got some input.. why?
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:baza");
        System.out.println("DBConnection: 'Connected'");
    }
}
```

Comment: S̶e̶e̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶s̶t̶a̶c̶k̶o̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶/̶1̶8̶2̶8̶8̶0̶5̶8̶/̶h̶o̶w̶-̶i̶s̶-̶d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶-̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶-̶l̶o̶c̶a̶t̶e̶d̶-̶i̶n̶-̶j̶d̶b̶c̶4̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶o̶a̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶o̶m̶a̶t̶i̶c̶a̶l̶l̶y̶.̶ The JDBC-ODBC driver is part of the JRE and thus it is loaded automatically.

Comment: I reach the call to getConnection() with your example.

Comment: That's strange. I copied all my code and it's not working. I didn't write; i thought it's not relevant but here we go: It was build by NetBeans 8.0 Platform JDK 1.7, on WindowsXP. As soon as i try on other machine (cant do that today), i'll post here. But it would be best solution because i couldn't see connection why deadlock there..
Thank you feuerball on your reply!!

Comment: I do not get a connection, because I do not have access to the database, but I get an exception and if I remove the call, `DBConnection: 'Connected'` is printed. Maybe there is a problem with your connection with the database. Try to remove the call and see if the string is printed.

Comment: Dont comment/remove DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:baza");. Because that method is one making the lock. If you can than make dummy MSAcess database and register it in windows ODBC giving it symbolic name 'baza'. So that url (getConnection("jdbc:odbc:baza");) could locate it.

Answer (score -1):

> My program works with and without it? Does java load driver by default?

From `Java 7` which uses `JDBC 4` this is optional. It will automatically find the correct driver class in the classpath and load it. There is no need to load it using  `Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");`. But for earlier versions you have to.

Also about your deadlock issue if the reason in really what you are saying is then you can call a `join()` after starting the thread

```
thread.start();
thread.join();
```

If you say that your code is waiting at

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:baza");
```

and it seems like a deadlock situation as even scanner is waiting for user input then I think that your connection is taking too long to be connected. You can try by specifying a timeout for this. You can do that by

```
DriverManger.setLoginTimeout(10);
```

Comment: This answers second half of my question! as for the first part i wanted to understand why deadlock is happening. I know you can always get around things :-) Many thanks Aniket! :-D

Comment: Please take a look at the edited answer and see of that helps.

Comment: GetConnection() is working fine and connects immediately if it reaches before the 'FIRST' thread. If it doesn't reach first, it hangs until scanner unblocks 'SECOND' thread. With timeout i would only cancel establishment of connection, so it's not an option :-(

Comment: Ohh.. In that case context switch is not happening and that should not happen in systems supporting multi programming. If you are using an IDE you could debug the code. Also prior to that in debug point properties set debug method to thread level.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you Aniket for replying